# Numbers in power mode in PL/SQL developer - switch to numerical sequence

Tags: plsql, number-formatting

In PL/SQL developer, I have a table column with format NUMBER(19).

The longer numbers are displayed in power mode instead of plain digital sequence, e.g.

`1,2345678901234E15`

instead of

`1234567890123456`

So the last digits are lost - also when I export the results as .csv or .xls.

How can I change display to numerical sequence?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague has found it in https://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=61009:

[Configure >] Preferences > [Window Types >] SQL Window > (Checkbox:) Number fields to_char